# In mongodb operator $expr gives an issue

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

the query works fine in the console but not working while executing with nodejs. I am using mongoose version 4.6.1. Can this be also an issue.

Input: Database sample input is below

```
{
id : ObjectId('5457782478124782374hfyud3eyw'),
model_id : 3000,
parent_id : 3000,
status : 1,
createdAt : ISODate("2018-05-30T09:40:10.784Z"),
updatedAt : ISODate("2018-05-30T09:40:10.784Z"),
}
```

Query: Following below is the query.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      status: { $ne: 3 },
      $or: [{ $expr: { $eq: ["$model_id", "$parent_id"] } }, { parent_id: 0 }]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$model_id",
      model_id: { $first: "$model_id" },
      make_id: { $first: "$make_id" },
      model_display_name: { $first: "$model_display_name" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { model_popularity_rank: -1 } }
];
```

error: MongoError: unknown top level operator: $expr

Comment: You are below the mongodb version **3.6**

Comment: version is 4.0.11

Comment: Okay Try to `setFeatureCompatiblityVersion` to **4.0.11**. `db.adminCommand({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: 4.0 })`

Comment: thanks but getting same error

Comment: Why are you using the `expr`? It is not needed in the query. Also, please post a sample input document.

Comment: The way to use the `$ne` looks different: [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/). Note that the operator syntaxes are different for same functionality in MongoDB _query language_ and [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Comment: i am using expr beacuse i need to compare value of two keys ('model_id' and 'parent_id')

Comment: the query works fine in the console but not working while executing with nidejs

Comment: I am using mongoose version 4.6.1. Can that be also an issue